# Jspdf height of PDF not working for images with long height

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/......" ;
var doc = new jsPDF();
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth;
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight;
 doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
  doc.save('img.pdf');
```

I am using above code to currently convert images into pdf long images like this https://cdn.black-clover.org/file/sugois/Reality-Quest/Chapter-1/03.jpg doesn't gets its height in pdf it only shows a part of image in pdf, any way to get its full height content while keeping the width on same ratio, you can check the demo by compiling the code above. Thanks in advance. You can check the fiddle here:- https://jsfiddle.net/5v91exfs/

Comment: Any way to know the preferred ratio for different images?

Comment: So it would be tough get the image ratio just using logics?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you with these types of silly questions. Thanks again

Comment: The height isn't problem the thing is width I can't  too figure it out how can I make different images with different ratio fit the full width for images as above

Comment: Thanks for your effort till now I will be busy researching and solving that problem thanks again

Comment: As you told jspdf is thinking there are 54 pixels per inches i tried using (img.height/96) * 54 in multiple images and it works

Comment: You are pretty good at math gladly divide by 96 mulitpled 54 is working perfectly for almost 41 images till now